# Importing hdbscan in QGIS plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, clustering

I am building a QGIS plugin and would like to add hdbscan in methods. 
But when I import with OSGEO4W shell it failed at this line:

> File
>   "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\hdbscan-0.8.22-py3.7-win32.egg\hdbscan_init_.py",
>   line 1, in from .hdbscan_ import HDBSCAN, hdbscan File
>   "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\hdbscan-0.8.22-py3.7-win32.egg\hdbscan\hdbscan_.py",
>   line 21, in from ._hdbscan_linkage import (single_linkage,
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

When I use QGIS python console it somehow failed at another line:

> File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in
>   import mod = builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>   File
>   "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\hdbscan-0.8.22-py3.7-win32.egg\hdbscan_init.py",
>   line 1, in from .hdbscan import HDBSCAN, hdbscan File
>   "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
>   mod = builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level) File
>   "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\hdbscan-0.8.22-py3.7-win32.egg\hdbscan\hdbscan.py",
>   line 21, in from ._hdbscan_linkage import (single_linkage, File
>   "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
>   mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I am using QGIS 3.8.2 and windows 7, python 3.7.0 32 bit on win32
I installed hdbscan 0.8.22 manually via python setup.py install